# Why isn't my blog posting?

Tags: php, sql, database, mysqli, blogs

My blog was posting originally, however, as you work on things, things break. Now I can't for the life of me figure out why nothing is happening! The categories post to the database just fine, but my posts refuse to.  Heres what I have

```
<?php
include_once('header.php');

if(isset($_POST['title'], $_POST['contents'], $_POST['category'])){
    $errors = array();
    if(!empty(trim($_POST['title']))){
        $title = trim($_POST['title']);
    }else{
        $errors[] = 'Please enter title';
    }
    if(!empty(trim($_POST['contents']))){
        $contents = trim($_POST['contents']);
    }else{
        $errors[] = 'You need to supply the content';
    }
    if(!category_id_exists($_POST['category'])){
        $errors[] = 'That category does not exist.';
    }
    if(strlen(trim($_POST['title']))>255){
        $errors[] = 'The title cannot be longer than 255 characters.'; 
    }

    if(empty($errors)){
        add_post($title, $contents, $_POST['category']);
        $id = mysqli_insert_id($mysql_connect);
        $header_string = 'Location: index.php?id='.$id;
        header($header_string);
        die();
    }

} 
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">

    <style>
        label { display: block;}
    </style>

    <title>Add a Post</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1> Add a Post </h1>
    <?php 
    if(isset($errors) && !empty($errors)){
        echo '<ul><li>', implode('</li><li>', $errors), '</li></ul>';
    }
    ?>

    <form action="" method="post">
        <div>
            <label for="title"> Title </label>
            <input type="text" name="title" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['title'])) echo $_POST['title']; ?>">
        </div>
        <div>
            <label for="contents"> Contents </label>
            <textarea name="contents" rows="15" cols="50"><?php if(isset($_POST['contents'])) echo $_POST['contents']; ?></textarea>
        </div>
        <div>
            <label for="category"> Category </label>
            <select name="category">
                <?php
                foreach(get_categories() as $category){
                    ?>
                    <option value="<?php echo $category['id']; ?>"><?php echo $category['name']; ?> </option>
                    <?php
                }
                ?>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div>
            <input type="submit" value="Add Post">
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Inside the header.php file, I call an init.php connect to db file which also in itself, include_once all the functions for my blog (blog.php). The function that specifically is necessary is as follows...

```
function add_post($title, $contents, $category){
    global $mysql_connect;

    $title = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysql_connect, $title);
    $contents = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysql_connect, $contents);
    $category = (int)$category;

    $result = mysqli_query($mysql_connect, "INSERT INTO posts SET cat_id = '$category', title = '$title', contents = '$contents', date_posted = NOW()");
}
```

I figured a fresh set of eyes could be really valuable for me right now. When I click add post, it brings me to a page titled http://localhost/blog/index.php?id=0. Therefore it's not only not registering to the database, but it's not using the categories either.

I hope I explained this okay! I've been at this for a week now.

Edit: I ran error checks and nothing posts, so I am not sure what's going on!

Edit2: Selecting categories I add, also work and list the way I want them to. Its just something happening when I go to click add post, nothing occurs. I'm assuming its in this area

```
if(empty($errors)){
    add_post($title, $contents, $_POST['category']);
    $id = mysqli_insert_id($mysql_connect);
    $header_string = 'Location: index.php?id='.$id;
    header($header_string);
    die();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As with any problem, it's always a needle in a haystack! I ran code through MYSQL workbench, and found out it was my setting to a foreign key that didn't need a relationship. It's all fixed now!

[SQL Error Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jVLl9.png)

Comment: How did you fix it? did you delete the foreign key from the structure?

Comment: Yes deleting the foreign key from the structure allowed my posts to work just fine. They still reference the other table, the foreign key was just irrelevant in this case, as my methods don't utilize it in a relational standpoint. It still displays the posts and categories they are apart of, now that I removed it :) 

https://imgur.com/lpn503O
https://imgur.com/OMmNd3k

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is with your database table `posts`.

**One Case is:**

You need to have an `AUTO_INCREMENT` field (`id` for example) so that the function `mysqli_insert_id` works perfectly. And in your case the solution would be to make the id column an `AUTO_INCREMENT` field.

[image]

**Here is a quote:**

> The mysqli_insert_id() function returns the ID generated by a query on
>   a table with a column having the AUTO_INCREMENT attribute. If the last
>   query wasn't an INSERT or UPDATE statement or if the modified table
>   does not have a column with the AUTO_INCREMENT attribute, this
>   function will return zero.

Comment: Assuming the problem is with the `$id = mysqli_insert_id($mysql_connect);` line.

Comment: Unfortunately, it is set to auto increment. it was working fine originally.  I was hoping that was the issue!

Comment: What is the name of the auto increment field in your `posts` table?

Comment: it is called "id"